# How to collect input data from the all edit text fields in the list made using recycle view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I'm working on an app in which one of the activities is using recycler list view to take inputs from the user. The list view is populated with one text view and one edit Text view.

So imagine, I have three items in the list. I need the inputs of the three edit Text views in different variables so that i can use those inputs in another activities. In my app, the number of items in the list is dependent on the user's input in a previous activity.

So I am unable to figure out how to take the input from each element in this list view and store it separately as the list is made using custom adapter class.

Myadapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Mydata> items;

View v;
// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Mydata> mydata) {
    this.items = mydata;
}


// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder



public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public View view;
    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        view = v;
    }
}


// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    // create a new view
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjectentry, parent, false);
     return new MyViewHolder(v);
}





// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
   TextView SubjectNumber = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.subjectNumber);
    EditText SubjectName = (EditText)holder.view.findViewById(R.id.subjectName);

    SubjectNumber.setText(items.get(position).getSubNumber());
    SubjectName.setText(items.get(position).getSubName());

}



// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

}

subjectentry.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subjectNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background=" #197ee3"
    android:hint="Number"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/subjectName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/subjectNumber"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/subjectNumber"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/subjectNumber"
    android:background="#8cbef1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Comment: add your recyclerview adapter code

Comment: @H.sanati Just did so.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the edit text value in adapter and send the data through  LocalBroadcastManager

> LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

```
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null, true);
            holder.spinner = convertView.findViewById(R.id.scan_name);
            holder.rate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.scan_rate);
            holder.floa=convertView.findViewById(R.id.sca);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

        final scan_setter row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        status=0;
         pos=getCount();

        holder.spinner.setText(row_pos.getPname());
        holder.rate.setText(row_pos.getPrate());

        holder.floa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dvalue= Integer.parseInt(row_pos.getPrate());
                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                intent.putExtra("key",dvalue);
                rowItems.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface for notifying the activity in order to an input (EditText) is changed and store the new value.

create InputListener.java file and write:

```
public interface InputListener{
   void onChangeInputValue(String newValue, int position);
}
```

in your activity implement the interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implement InputListener {
    //...

    @Override
    public void onChangeInputListener(String newValue, int position) {
        // here you can collect input data of each editText
    }

    //...
}
```

and in the constructor of your adapter, you must get an `InputListener` object. (in this example the `MainActivity` is an instance of InputListener)

RecyclerView code section:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
     private ArrayList<Mydata> items;
     private InputListener listener;

     public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Mydata> mydata, InputListener listener) {
         this.items = mydata;
         this.listener = listener;
     }

  public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         public EditText subjectName;
         public TextView subjectNumber;

         public MyViewHolder(View v) {
             super(v);
             SubjectNumber = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.subjectNumber);
             SubjectName = (EditText)holder.view.findViewById(R.id.subjectName);

         }
     }

     @Override
     public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

         RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subjectentry, parent, false);
          return new MyViewHolder(v);
     }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
         SubjectNumber.setText(items.get(position).getSubNumber());
         SubjectName.setText(items.get(position).getSubName());

        SubjectName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                 listener.onChangeInputValue(charSequence, position);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
    });
     }


     @Override
     public int getItemCount() {
         return items.size();
     }
```

Comment: "holder.input.addOnTextChangeListener(//)" -  I presume the 'input' should be a text field where my text will be entered right?  But i'm using a custom view because i have two fields in my list. I didn't really understand this. Could you help?

Comment: @HarshPatel you implement adapter in wrong way, see my edited answer.